# How do I debug Magento report with no error?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, debugging

I have a module that I created that stores data posted via form to a custom table and then sends a confirmation email.

I got to a point of testing the form action, and it gets there - but I get the "There has been an error processing your request" message.

Going to that report number in var/report shows this:

```
$ cat 1569284307198 
a:5:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:715:"#0 /var/www/staging/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Namespace_Module_IndexController->postAction()
#1 /var/www/staging/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('post')
#2 /var/www/staging/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#3 /var/www/staging/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#4 /var/www/staging/site/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#5 /var/www/staging/site/index.php(101): Mage::run('', 'store')
#6 {main}";s:3:"url";s:28:"/frontname/index/post/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

It may just be my inexperience, but there's nothing there that actually helps me find out what's wrong with my code.

How do I find out what's wrong with my code (not necessarily what is wrong with my code)?

Comment: "Namespace_Module_IndexController->postAction()" is this name correct in you code namespace and module name in you file is correct?

Comment: @AsadUllah indeed it is :) but I think I know the issue, I think it has something to do with the attempted sending of the email because that's the last step in my code, and everything before that happens (the db insert works etc.) - so I think it's to do with the email server rather than the code now... still.. would be nice if Magento logged that type of error better

Comment: that's great if you have found the issue